# Hover is not working in mobile device touch - Ionic mobile application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to develop an application . I am trying to apply some css on hover(on touch on mobile). it is working well in browser but not working in the real device.

Please help me to resolve the problem.

What is way to proceed to apply css for touch event.

The element:

```
<div class="deviceListItem">
  <i class="myIcon ion-ios-unlocked-outline" ></i> <br>
  Door Open
 </div>
```

CSS for the element:

```
 .myIcon  {
     background-color: #fff !important;
     color: #000 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
```

CSS for Hover effect:

```
  .myIcon:hover  {
     background-color: #0078D7 !important;
     color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    box-shadow:0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
```

Comment: did you try this using different versions?

Comment: @Muhsin yes i tried with different systems and versions..it is not working.

Comment: I have done this feature.But it was not working in some versions

Comment: @Muhsin could you please share the version details if you have ?

Comment: android 4.2,android 5